# Good books/resources for learning how to visualize Mobius transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, linear-transformations, big-list

Posts like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021316/mapping-a-region-between-two-circles-on-a-half-plane/4219901#4219901) have always baffled me. I have taken a few complex variables courses in my time and it seems that every time I take a course like this, either the textbook isn't great at explaining how, for example, a circle "becomes" a straight line or the instructor isn't great at explaining the concept.

I'm currently looking at Ahlfors's *Complex Analysis* where Ahlfors introduces such concepts via Mobius transformations, but he does not go into great detail explaining the transforming of regions of the plane into various shapes and objects.

What are good resources for teaching oneself the visualization behind Mobius transformations (e.g. mapping a circle into a straight line and so on)?

Comment: You might like the book Visual Complex Analysis by Tristan Needham.

Comment: I think there is some confusion, and that you mean "Mobius transformations" instead of "linear transformations". A map taking a circle to a straight line is not linear. On the other hand, it is true that any Mobius transformation transforms circles/lines to circles/lines. But if you were googling for "linear transformations", these wouldn't have come up.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thank you for correcting me. I think I meant to say linear *fractional* transformation which is equivalent to what you're mentioning. I've edited the post

Comment: This video is rather old now but still quite a good visualization of the Mobius transformation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY